# How do you write a javascript CLI without exiting node environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know it is possible to write a command line interface with node but all examples i have found so far is simply passing parameters in the terminal that will execute a node script and then immediately exit the node environment, loosing all its variables and state.

For example if i have an api with a login function and another function which depend on the auth state i want to do everything inside node.

I know this way works but there must be a better way that is more straight forward than writing require in the terminal every single time?

```
$. node
$. let api = require('./myApi')

$. api.login()
$. api.fetchData()
```

Answer (score -1):

This appears to do what you're asking for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-repl